# How does Xbox One work with Microsoft's TV tuner and TV itself?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm planning to buy an Xbox One and a Microsoft TV tuner. I want to know if I need two IR controls or can I use only the Xbox's one (without the TV control). Is Xbox able to turn on and off my TV when I turn on and off (sleep) the Xbox?

Thank you.